# On Button Click Hide Keyboard

Tags: android

I have a meme creator application, I have two text fields and a button, I want when the button is pressed to hide the keyboard, is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried this far? It's commonly expected on StackOverflow that questions show some effort in terms of actual code.

Comment: first help yourself by trying it on your own

Comment: Post your code what u have tried.

Comment: add to onClickListener [hide softkeyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1109108/4149649)

Comment: What have you tried on your own? Did you even try to search for this on google? If I google your title, you will get the answer in the first hit

Comment: Sorry for my question, I've resolved it, I am noob at stackoverflow, I haven't thought that someone has the same question as me :))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public void dismissKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (null != activity.getCurrentFocus())
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus()
                .getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Activity have to be passed to this method, Keyboard will get dismissed.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide sof keyboard with this lines

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                                  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                                     InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Put this in the onClick(View view) event.

You need to import `android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager`;

The keyboard will hides when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

What you want should already be happening. When you click the button, the focus changes from the text field to the button, so the keyboard will automatically hide.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textBox);

InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

this should be in button click event

Answer (score 0):

**Android Kotlin**

> On button click hide the keyboard in kotlin

```
fun dismissKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
    val imm = activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    if (null != activity.currentFocus) imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
        activity.currentFocus!!.applicationWindowToken, 0
    )
}
```

> And use in your class like this

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    dismissKeyboard(this)
}
```